# VS Code UI shows no text

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to Ubuntu Desktop.

I installed VS Code via official website. After installation, I tried to run, but the app shows no text at all. I don't know if it's related to fonts, but when I watched videos installing VS Code on Ubuntu, it ran well without any further configs.

The following screenshot illustrates the issue:
[image]

I'm installing Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS on a VM using UTM on M1 MacBook Pro 13".
The host operating system is macOS Monterey 12.6.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue using an Ubuntu 20.04 VM in UTM with an M1 Macbook, I managed to get it working by disabling gpu acceleration.

Try running VS Code using the following command in the terminal:

`code --disable-gpu`

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Starting VS Code in the terminal with `--disable-gpu` as suggested by [jimmy123](https://askubuntu.com/a/1453026/127877) fixes this issue for this session, to fix this long term, you have to delete the GPU cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Code/GPUCache/
```